# Issue with intel_extension_for_pytorch

Tags: ubuntu, pytorch, intel, patch

I have just installed the intel extension for pytorch.
it is installed, however, I cannot import it.
has anyone encountered such an issue and any suggestions?

I have already installed the drivers and oneAPI Base Toolkit Update the Bash set up everything in a new environment and using the relevant version of python (3.10) for torch==2.0.1a0 and intel_extension_for_pytorch==2.0.110+xpu.

I expected to be able to import it after installation, while I cant :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[8], line 2
      1 import torch
----> 2 import intel_extension_for_pytorch as ipex
      4 import torchvision.models as models
      5 model = models.resnet50(pretrained=True)

File ~/mambaforge/envs/pytorch-arc/lib/python3.10/site-packages/intel_extension_for_pytorch/__init__.py:93
     89                 raise err
     91     kernel32.SetErrorMode(prev_error_mode)
---> 93 from .utils._proxy_module import *
     94 from . import cpu
     95 from . import xpu

File ~/mambaforge/envs/pytorch-arc/lib/python3.10/site-packages/intel_extension_for_pytorch/utils/_proxy_module.py:2
      1 import torch
----> 2 import intel_extension_for_pytorch._C
      5 # utils function to define base object proxy
      6 def _proxy_module(name: str) -> type:

ImportError: libmkl_sycl.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```